Is it possible to instruct jmxexporter to skip certain values inside a composite attribute?
I'm using jmxexporter to get the metrics from JMX MBean tableau.health.jmx:name=vizqlservice which has a composite attribute called PerformanceMetrics, this composite attribute has hundreds of attributes inside:  ActiveSession, SessionsInFlightCount, IdleSessionsIdleCount, etc.
I only want to expose a selected set of those, I see from jmxexporter 0.20 documentation that I can exclude attributes but in this case there is a single attribute PerformanceMetrics.
This is the configuration for the jmxexporter that I'm using
cat jmxexporter_vizqlserver1_config.yaml
---
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:8893/jmxrmi
includeObjectNames:
        - "java.lang:type=Memory,*"
        - "tableau.health.jmx:*"
excludeObjectNameAttributes:
        "java.lang:type=Memory":
                - NonHeapMemoryUsage
                - Verbose
                - ObjectPendingFinalizationCount

java -jar jmx_prometheus_httpserver-0.20.0.jar 12345 jmxexporter_vizqlserver1_config.yaml

curl -s http://localhost:12345|grep -e "^\(tableau\|java\)_"
# way to many metrics 

Is there any way to filter specific attributes inside a composite attribute from jmxexporter itself?

Currently (jmxexporter 0.20) does not allow to filter out individual attributes within a larger composite attribute.
You can follow Issue #961 on prometheus/jmx_exporter project
